# Strict comparisons problem when using boolean post meta

Tags: post-meta

```
register_meta(
    'post',
    'my_boolean_meta_value',
    array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'type'         => 'boolean',
        'single'       => true,
        'default'      => true,
    )
);
update_post_meta(166,'my_boolean_meta_value',false);
update_post_meta(167,'my_boolean_meta_value',true);
$false_value=get_post_meta(166,'my_boolean_meta_value',true);
$true_value=get_post_meta(167,'my_boolean_meta_value',true);
if (false === $false_value) {
    echo "Verified false_value is false." . '<br>';
}
if (true === $true_value) {
    echo "Verified true_value is true";
}
if ('' === $false_value) {
    echo "Verified false_value is an empty string. " . '<br>';
}
if ('1' === $true_value) {
    echo "Verified true_value is '1'";
}
```

The expected output should indicate that $true_value is `true`, and $false_value is `false`.  Instead the output is:

```
Verified false_value is an empty string.
Verified true_value is '1'
```

Can we expect in future versions of WordPress that boolean meta data will always return an empty string instead if `false` and a string of '1' instead of `true`?

Comment: Does it matter exactly what the value is, as long as `if ($value)` works correctly?

Comment: if future versions of WP changed the behaviour and returned something different, it would be considered a major backwards compatibility bug. Note that `get_post_meta` might not be querying the database here as those values get cached in the object cache, otherwise it is documented that on failure `get_post_meta` will return a `false` value

Comment: Also `echo ( 'foo' === 'bar' )` will output `''`, you can't `echo` the output to get the type, `echo false` does not print `false`, you need a more specific test, such as `var_dump`, e.g. `var_dump( false );` which prints `bool(false)`

Comment: Rup, Good Point.  phpcs does not complain about using `if ($value)` like it complains about using `if (false == $value)`, and it produces the desired result.

Comment: @MeyerAuslander, are you aware that the boolean `true` is saved as `1`, whereas `false` is saved as an empty string (`''`) in the database? So `get_post_meta()` did return the correct values because in the database, we could have exactly `NULL` (and not the string `"NULL"`) as the value, but not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @Rup, sometimes it is preferred to check the value if the boolean post meta using `($value === <WordPress true>)` instead of `if ($value)`, e.g., when filtering a post listing in the Admin by the boolean meta's value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Tom, in the comments on the question, it seems not likely that WordPress will change their standard for storing/returning boolean post meta, due to backward compatibility issues.  However, I thought of some ways to write code that will work even if the WordPress standard does change their standard:

- Always convert Boolean Post Meta data to it's exact boolean value using the php [`boolval` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php).  e.g., `boolval( get_post_meta( $id, 'my_boolean_post_meta', true ) );`.  If so, it will now work to do strict comparisons to `true` or `false`.
- Utilize some other post meta data type like `string` or `integer` to implement boolean variables.  Choose your own standards for what value will be true and false.  Then define them as global constants.

BTW, even though WordPress stores `true` as '1' and `false` as '', the following meta queries still work (at least up to version 5.7.2):
For getting true values:

```
array(
    'key'     => 'my_boolean_post_meta',
    'value'   => true,
    'compare' => '=',
),
```

For getting false values:

```
array(
    'key'     => 'my_boolean_post_meta',
    'value'   => false,
    'compare' => '=',
),
```

It seems `'compare' => '='` does not result in a strict comparison.

Comment: "the following meta queries still work" - yes that's right, because for example with the first meta query clause, the generated SQL statement would have something like `wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1'` and not `wp_postmeta.meta_value = true`, although MySQL does support that boolean comparison.